# Manually add location to a photo in iPhone, without Mac

Tags: iphone, photos

I have taken some pictures with my iPhone 6 when the localization functionality was deactivated. Now, I'd like to manually add the location to these pictures, to let them appear in the map of the Photo app.
But I don't know how to do it. I read many posts regarding the Photo application on Mac, but unfortunately I don't own a computer running Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location data is stored in EXIF data structures embedded in pictures, EXIF editors are available in the App Store, just search for „EXIF“. [Exif Editor & Viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/exif-editor-und-viewer/id560004690?mt=8) seems to be a likely candidate.

Comment: Thank you! I have used Exif Viewer Lite. I've been able to modify them.